# Double wiggly line with arrow using feynmf

Tags: arrows, feynmf, feynman

Please, could you help me to draw a double wiggly line with an arrow? I can drow a single woggly line with arrow using this code

```
  \begin{fmffile}{vertex}
  \fmfcmd{%
  style_def wiggly_arrow expr p =
  cdraw (wiggly p);
  shrink (1);
  cfill (arrow p);
  endshrink;
  enddef;}
  \begin{fmfgraph*}(100,60)
  \fmfleft{i1}
  \fmfright{o1,o2}
  \fmflabel{$g$}{v1}
  \fmf{wiggly_arrow,label=$\hat{a}$,l.side=left}{i1,v1}
  \fmf{fermion,label=$\sigma$,l.side=right}{v1,o1}
  \fmf{dashes_arrow,label=$\hat{D}$,l.side=left}{v1,o2}
  \fmfdotn{v}{1}
  \end{fmfgraph*}
  \end{fmffile}
```

When I just change "wiggly" by "dbl_wiggly", this code no longer works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really care for the look of this but the following does produce a double wiggly line with an arrowhead superimposed near the center:

```
\begin{fmffile}{vertex}
  \fmfcmd{%
  style_def dbl_wiggly_arrow expr p =
  draw_double (wiggly p);
  shrink (1);
  cfill (arrow p);
  endshrink;
  enddef;}
  \begin{fmfgraph*}(100,60)
  \fmfleft{i1}
  \fmfright{o1,o2}
  \fmflabel{$g$}{v1}
  \fmf{dbl_wiggly_arrow,label=$\hat{a}$,l.side=left}{i1,v1}
  \fmf{fermion,label=$\sigma$,l.side=right}{v1,o1}
  \fmf{dashes_arrow,label=$\hat{D}$,l.side=left}{v1,o2}
  \fmfdotn{v}{1}
  \end{fmfgraph*}
  \end{fmffile}
```

Note the `draw_double (wiggly p)` in place of the more obvious `cdraw (dbl_wiggly p)`.

Comment: Dear @Dan, thank you very much! This works well!